# Convert Matrix element wise definition to matrix ops

Tags: matrices, brownian-motion

Given a matrix $[min(s,t]_{st}$ how can it be represented in terms of matrix operations?

For scalars, $min(s,t) = \frac{1}{2}(s + t - |s - t|)$.

The objective here is to find the conditional covariance and mean of a Brownian motion given $W_t = w_t,\ 0 \le t \le 1$

Comment: There is a nice factorization for $[\frac{1}{\max(s,t)}]_{s,t}$ (see Horn and Johnson problem 3.5.P7), but I don't see a direct connection to this problem.

Comment: I also vaguely recall that the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1&\cdots\\1&2&2&\cdots\\1&2&3&\cdots\\ & \vdots}
$$
is connected to tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices, but I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following useful: if $M$ is a matrix with entries $M_{s,t} = \min\{s,t\}$, then we have $M = AA^T$ with $A$ equal to the lower triangular matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\1&1\\ \vdots & & \ddots \\1& \cdots &&1}.
$$
It is also notable that $M^{-1}$ has the nice form
$$
M^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&-2\\-2&\ddots & \ddots\\&\ddots&&-2\\&&-2&1}.
$$